# echoing user inputs from one page to other page

Tags: php

So what I am trying to do is

I have a page called jobspost.php where It would take the some inputs from user and than I want to post that information on jobs.php through code no manually.

is that possible, if yes can you please give me a hint or a block of code.

Simple example :

Thanks,

Malav

Comment: With a form, you can use POST variables to show inputs given from one page to another. I.e.: `<input type="text" name="first_name">` in the form, then in PHP handler `$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];` then `echo $first_name;` type of thing. Very basic example. You can Google "php form variables".

Comment: Take input from user and then post through code not manually? Shouldn't the input be manually entered and posted with a button? If not, it sounds like you might need some Javascript. But it sounds like POST and the $_POST suberglobal is at least the way to go.

Comment: what if the input is a text with attached file? will it still help?

Comment: @MalavShah What do you mean "attached file"? Show me an example. Can't be done. Text is text, file is a file. Two different animals altogether.

Comment: I am sorry but i meant to say that it should take input from user and when user hits the button it should automatically post that information on the jobs.php

Comment: @MalavShah OOoohhhhh "that". Sure, it can be done and append/add to existing data. Yet the use of a DB is better.

Comment: @MalavShah Just Google "php fwrite forms" and you'll get a whole bunch of results.

Comment: ok. let me make more clear. I have a text box and file uploader. text box takes the "job description" and file uploader uploads a pdf containing information of that job. <INPUT TYPE = "Text" VALUE ="Description" NAME = "jd">   and upload box code is <form action="jobpost.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for your comment. will get back if i need help

Comment: @MalavShah You're welcome. Now with what you posted above, will now need a PHP handler and assign those variables, then use the `fwrite()` function to write to file.

Comment: @MalavShah By the way, it's not a file "uploader" that you need, it's a "write to file" function => http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for all the information. but I guess fwrite is not going to work for me. let me explain you more on what I exactly like to do. As i said, there are 2 pages, 1st page is jobpost.php and 2nd page is jobs.php. now jobpost.php takes a string (which is description) and file uploader (which will help to upload a pdf file). now once both fields are provided by user and user hits post button, jobs.php should have a link to that pdf(which is uploaded) with the string as its caption. Again thank you..

Comment: @MalavShah Ah ok, now I got the whole picture. And may I ask if you already tried something? It is doable.

Comment: @Fred-ii-well I looked up lot things and tried different things such as fwrite as suggested by you, putting data on dbserver and calling with a query which did work but i dont want that page to connect to database unless i dont have alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but the general approach to your problem is (i think) hidden fields. Hidden fields can store information when a site is generated, and their value can again be sent if the user submits a form, thus automatically passing some pieces of "hidden information".

```
<input type="hidden" name="variable" value="theValue">
```

Just add it to the form you are using and make sure your script is setting it when generating the page!

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to SO.